# Remove some tags in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use jquery to remove some tags inside mainclass, so that this -

```
<div class='mainclass'>
<div class='inclass'>
<a href='#'>Some text</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Becomes this -

```
<div class='mainclass'>
Some text
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.mainclass').text($('.inclass').text());`

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know .text() would ignore the html tags.  Makes sense though.

Answer (score 0):

Store the text you want to preserve, remove the elements and set the text to the main div.

```
var sometext = $('.mainclass > .inclass > a').text();
$('.mainclass').remove('.inclass').text(sometext);
```

Comment: .remove won't save the text within the inclass div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mainclass').html($('.inclass > a').text());
```

Comment: **WRONG WRONG WRONG!** That's an XSS hole.  (What if the text is `<script>...</script>`?)

Comment: Depends how it's being used I guess. I don't follow how the text could end up as script tags though.

Comment: Like this: `<a>Evil: &lt;script&gt;alert('XSS!');&lt;/script&gt;</a>`